# A pretty simple UPDATE InnoDB query taking too much

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

Basically I have this simple query:

```
UPDATE beststat 
  SET rawView = rawView + 1 
  WHERE bestid = 139664 AND period = 201205 
  LIMIT 1
```

It takes **1 sec**.

This table (beststat) currently has **~1mil** record and its size is: **68MB**. I have **4GB RAM** and `innodb buffer pool size` = **104,857,600**, with: Mysql: **5.1.49-3**

This is the only InnoDB table in my database (others are MyISAM)

---

I have `unique key index` on bestid and period of course:

```
CREATE TABLE `beststat` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `bestid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `period` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `view` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `rawView` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `bestid` (`bestid`,`period`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2020577 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

---

```
EXPLAIN SELECT rawView FROM beststat WHERE bestid =139664 AND period =201205 LIMIT 1
```

Gives:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  beststat    const   bestid  bestid  7   const,const 1
```

Any help ?

Comment: The `LIMIT 1` clause seems unnecessary. Have you run an `EXPLAIN` on the query? Is it properly using the index?

Comment: @llion: you can't explain UPDATE/INSERT query. And i doubt that LIMIT 1 affectes performance

Comment: Could you `EXPLAIN SELECT rawView FROM betstat WHERE bestid = 139664 AND period = 201205 LIMIT 1` instead?  With a table of that size, you might consider [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning.html) it on `bestid`.

Comment: Shall you publish io[disc r/w might be an issue here] on the server while you continuously fire the same UPDATE query as I mentioned in my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has to scan the entire table in order to do the update.

Add a composite index on (bestid, period) or change the query to use id.

Comment: Gorden Linoff... why so the query is supposed to scan the entire table though it has the unique key... i dont think so that the unique key does not serve the indexing needs as it is like PRIMARY key which will allow NULLs. shall you please elaborate on Y u suggested so....

Comment: gordon: i have a composite index on that

Comment: My bad.  I clearly missed the UNIQUE KEY line when I was looking at the code.  I declare my indexes separately from the constraints to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

When you access an innodb table for the first time, the time it will show include the time it takes to load the index data into the buffer pool. consider the timelines of further firings.

If the details you published are of seconds and later query execution timelines only,

> CHECK whether the table is FRAGMENTED or NOT. 
>     In case of a fragmentted table, the actual look up for UPDATE is more than it is supposed 
>     to.

If even this is not the case, look at the below variables.

```
1) innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit
   In general there will be 30 - 40% degraded performance with    
   innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit set to 1 than it is set to 2

2) innodb_flush_method.
   Default fsync will perfrom worse than the O_DIRECT and O_SYNC
```

Finally go for the PROFILING information and see the IO on the server[sar OR iostat] while you are executing the query continuouslu with SQL_NO_CACHE